# Why does macOS Mojave change a group's name automatically?

Tags: user-account, group, acl

Created a user group called "`Duo`". When I add it to a directory, macOS Mojave (10.14.6) automatically changes the name to "`Dev`".

[image]

Even `id` says my user is group "Dev" (and not "Duo" as it was named):

```
$ id
uid=502(s) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),505(Dev) ...
```

What's actually happening here?

Comment: Could it be autocorrection ? Have you tried issuing a `chown` command through Terminal, like `chown :Duo <filepath>` ?

Comment: `$ chown :Duo /Volumes/Backup/test` gives `chown: Duo: illegal group name`. When I try ":Dev" instead, it works fine. But the group is still listed as "Duo" in the "Users & Groups" system preference pane from where I created it.

Comment: I wrote `Duo`, but maybe your group is `duo`. Did you try both ?

Comment: Yes, both "Duo" and duo" do not work. chown only accepts "Dev".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. I had originally created a group called *Dev* and then immediately renamed it to *Duo* through `Users & Groups` in `System Preferences`. But appparently this only makes a **cosmetic** change in the gui. I don't know if this is an expected behaviour by design or a bug on macOS Mojave 10.14.6 ...

To reproduce it:

1. Open `System Preferences` > `Users & Groups` from the Apple menu.
2. Click the `Lock` icon and unlock as an administrator.
3. Click the `+` icon (below *Login Options*).
4. Select `Group` from the drop down menu of *New Account*.
5. Enter a name for the group in *Full Name* and click `Create Group`.
6. The new group will be immediately listed in the sidebar, under `Groups`.
7. Click on the newly created group name in the sidebar.
8. In the *Name* field, change the name of the group to something else.

**Expected**: macOS Mojave renames the group name.

**What actually happens**: macOS Mojave doesn't actually change the group name in the system and continues to use the original group name. But it shows the renamed group name in the macOS GUI (in `Users & Groups`).

***Tip***: To actually change the group name through `Users & Groups`, you have to right-click the group name in the sidebar, and click on `Advanced Options` and input the new name in `Group name` and click `OK`. (This introduces another weird behavior / bug for me - if you right-click and change the name through the `Advanced Options`, it won't be shown again to you in the same session - i.e. right-clicking the group name after renaming it won't show a right-click menu again.)

Answer (score 0):

Update: this was written based on an entirely incorrect interpretation of the OP's situation. Leaving it here anyway as a treatise on the difference between Contacts groups and directory groups.

---

Since it looks like you are trying to configure file permissions, you probably want to be using System Preferences to [view and edit system groups](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mh11775/10.14/mac/10.14), instead of Contacts to view and edit contacts groups.

To answer your question about what's going on: for the purposes of this discussion, macOS supports two different kinds of groups: *contacts groups* and *directory groups*. While they are pretty different, they have one thing in common: both provide a way to refer to a collection of one or more *records* - however the *type* of record supported by each is quite different, and these two different kinds of group records are not interchangeable.

- A [Contacts group](https://support.apple.com/guide/contacts/create-groups-of-contacts-adrb3280fe91/12.0/mac/10.14) (formerly known as 'AddressBook group') is a list of one or more [contact records](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontact). A contacts group provides a shortcut for addressing multiple contacts at once, for example when composing an email or group text. When you supply a contacts group as the recipient for an email, the group immediately expands to the list of individual records it contains, which is the exact same result you'd get as if you typed each address individually. Contacts groups are generally *only* useful for this purpose, as they can only contain contact *records*, which don't have all the attributes needed to do other things related to users or groups. Contacts records are stored in the contacts database, which is not used for any other purpose.
- "Directory groups" (aka "directory services groups", "unix groups", "system groups") are a more traditional and flexible [record type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/opendirectory/opendirectory_functions/record_types), commonly used when configuring [access privileges](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mh11775/10.14/mac/10.14) to [files](https://support.apple.com/en-in/guide/mac-help/mchlp1203/10.14/mac/10.14) or [services](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mh17131/10.14/mac/10.14). Directory groups contain *user records* (and / or other group records), which support a very rich set of attributes that go far beyond just contact-related information. User records define the set of names and passwords that can be used for *[authentication](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AuthenticationAndAuthorizationGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)*, while group records define lists of users that can be *[authorized](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AuthenticationAndAuthorizationGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)* to access some resource or perform some action. [Directory services records](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/opendirectory/opendirectory_functions/record_types) are stored in directory services databases which may be local or remote; on macOS, access to this data is brokered by [opendirectoryd](http://x-man-page://opendirectoryd).

I am tiptoeing around a complication that probably doesn't matter for your situation, but just for completeness: *user records* can also hold contact-related information, and can be used in many of the same ways as contacts records. By extension, the same is true of group records, which can also participate in contact-related workflows. macOS can bridge multiple different sources of contact information, so for example when addressing an email, macOS can search across local contact and contact group records, and also search a remote LDAP server that holds contacts records, and also a remote LDAP server that holds *directory services* records. This kind of thing can be configured with [Directory Utility](https://support.apple.com/guide/directory-utility/define-search-policies-diru978f56de/5.0/mac/10.14) - in particular, note that the search path for authentication can be configured separately from the search path for contacts.

Comment: I can’t see any evidence that OP has mistakenly used contact groups instead. The right group shows when running `id` which wouldn’t show contact groups afaik and Contacts isn’t selected in the screenshot. Why do you think contact groups are involved?

Comment: You're right; I mistook the first image as a Contacts screenshot.